# Post the value of a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to post the literal value of a button as form data but cannot achieve this. Here's what I have so far.

```
    <form method="POST" action="/post" id="message">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div style="line-height:22%;">
      </div>
      <button class="btn-change" type="submit" name="foo" value="bar"><dt><code>button for value bar</code></dt></button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".btn-change").on('click', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById('message').submit();
      });
    </script>
```

How do I post `value` in my form?

**Solution**

This seems to work:

```
<button class="btn-change" name="message" form="message" value="bar"><dt><code>button for value bar</code></dt></button>
```

With the removal of (of course):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".btn-change").on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    document.getElementById('message').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the value of the `value` attribute or you want the contents of the `button` element?

Comment: Why do you have this line at all `document.getElementById('message').submit()` since the form should submit when the button is clicked, and why is it in plain JS since you're using jQuery? Also what is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: `<button>` doesn't have `name` and `value` attribute, but `<input type="submit">` does.

Comment: @j08691 sorry for the confusion. (apologies) I am not a front end developer as you can see. I want the actual value of `value="bar"`, so I would like to submit form data with the value `"bar"` after a user clicks the button.

Comment: Then you have to use a form element that supports those attributes, `button` does not.

Comment: I was able to do it using `<button class="btn-change" name="message" form="message" value="bar">button for value bar</button>`

Answer (score -1):

Put the value in a hidden field to declare inside the form : `<input type="hidden" name="myvalue">`. It won't be displayed on screen, but you can store in it's value property anything you want to post.